# How to fire Click event of Check Box in asp.Net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a check box for "IsQuantityAvailable" for selecting if a seller have availability of commodities and **on CLICK of this chkBox I have to show a TextBox** for entering quantity of commodity.Please suggest a solution using MVC Razor...Thanks!!

Comment: The solution hasn't much to do with Razor, but more with maybe JavaScript.

Comment: There's no maybe about it.  This is all javascript; nothing to do with Razor.  It sounds like you're probably coming from an WebForms where controls had events.  In MVC, controls don't have server side events (and in fact there are no controls). The answer below will do you fine.

Answer (score 9):

As mario suggested, the solution hasn't much to do with razor, however this might help.
Create the checkbox using Html.Checkbox or Html.CheckboxFor if u have strict model binding. Add onclick eventhandler to checkbox while adding

```
@Html.Checkbox( "somename", new { @onclick="function-to-open-dialog()"})
```

Implementation of "function-to-open-dialog" will depend upon what you are using at client site. If its jquery then it could be simple call like $("#DialogId").dialog("open")